# How do you bind ObservableCollections to ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, wpf

```
DataContextDataContext context1 = new DataContextDataContext();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
        RadGridView1.Filtered+=new EventHandler<GridViewFilteredEventArgs>(RadGridView1_Filtered);
        ObservableCollection<MyObject> _MyObject = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
        foreach (var p in context1.Students)
        {
            _MyObject.Add(new MyObject { ID = p.StudentID, Name = p.StudentFN });
        }
    }

    void RadGridView1_Filtered(object sender, GridViewFilteredEventArgs e)
    {
        RadGridView1.ItemsSource = ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class MyObject
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

How do you bind my ObservableCollections to the ItemsSource?

Comment: protip:  `ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjects {get;set;}` Bindings to fields does NOT work (I'm surprised it works in the selected answer; might be because its a collection) and if you start getting in that habit you're going to spend a few days figuring out why your bindings fail.  Also, you might want to check out the framework guidelines.

Comment: where do i check it please guide me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to set the `ItemSource` to the instance of an `ObservableCollection` you created in the constructor:

```
RadGridView1.ItemsSource = _MyObject;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make the observable collection as a public property in your code-behind/presenter/viewmodel, like

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjectCollection {get;set;}
```

then you can populate that and the binding can be code code behind.

ItemsSource is a dependency property you can bind it in XAML or code behind, like suppose you want to bind to ListBox's(say named lstItems) ItemsSource, like (below code is considering that 'MyObjectCollection' is in codebehind

```
Binding bindingObject = new Binding("MyObjectCollection");
bindingObject.Source = this; //codebehind class instance which has MyObjectCollection
lstItems.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSource, bindingObject);
```

or in XAML,

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyObjectCollection}"/>
```

for both the ways above you need to set the datacontext which is 'this' (for this specific solution).

But maybe you want to look into basic WPF databinding where you can understand Depedency properties, binding objects, binding modes, etc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480224.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612.aspx
http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2008/05/19/gradual-introduction-to-wpf-data-binding/